# Text Mining with too much data

Tags: r, matrix, text-mining

I am trying to play with text mining tools that the R language offers but I am facing the following problem since I am running in an old machine.

I want to create a Document Term Matrix using the tm package and the Corpus function.
When I create the DTM I receive an error that can allocate memory of 4GB (My machine has 2 GB of memory). How in general do you face such a problem? For example, in general applications the DTM should be much greater than my matrix. Is there a way to use an SQL database instead of using the memory?

//I have studied a releated post about using the sqldf library in order to create a temporary sqlite database. But in this case I can not even create the matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How in general do you face such a problem?

Use a [sparse matrix data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix). Without that, text mining is pretty much impossible. With one, I can process 100s of 1000s of document in a few hundred MB.

I don't work in R myself, but it's bound to have a sparse matrix package somewhere.

Comment: This is not really a helpful answer because the Document Term Matrix produced by R's tm package is already a sparse matrix: http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/tm/docs/as.TermDocumentMatrix

Comment: @Ben: I see. But the OP's question was "How in general do you face such a problem?" and apparently this suggestion worked, so perhaps they were created a dense matrix first.